# Javascript SVG resize work on chrome but not safari

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser, webfonts

I've got some code which is designed to resize the text on an SVG so that it fits within a certain size.

It seems to work fine on chrome but not in any other browser (I tried IE11 and Safari).

This is the code

```
<html>
  <body>
  <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sonsie+One');
text {
  font-family: "Sonsie One";
}
svg {
  background: #43C6AC;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text id="t1" style="fill: white;" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">Test</text>
</svg>
<script>
function resize() { 
    var width = 350,
      height = 80;
    var textNode = document.getElementById("t1");
    for (var k = 1; k < 60; k++) {
      textNode.setAttribute("font-size", k)
      var bb = textNode.getBBox()
      if (bb.width > width || bb.height > height)
        break;
    }
}
window.onload = resize;      
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is it running on a url: http://hiven.com/momo.html

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? In chrome it resizes the text to 350px but in others it doesn't.

Comment: Works OK for me in Chrome, Firefox, Opera. IE does not work when the font is Sonsie One, but works OK otherwise. (Can't test in Safari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem is caused by timing of font loading. (I tested on Epiphany WEB which has WebKit rendering engine as Safari.)

Since `window.onload` is called before completion of font loading, `resize` method works under fallback font style, thus the text size gotten by `bbox` was incorrect.

So this problem is solved by waiting completion of font loading. But apis of font loading as `document.fonts.onloadingend` or `document.fonts.load` seem to be not supported on WebKit (or have no effect on this case).

Thus I made the waiting system by `canvas` element like this (but I think this is not best.)

```
<html>
  <body>
        <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sonsie+One');
    text {
        font-family: "Sonsie One";
    }
    svg {
        background: #43C6AC;
    }
        </style>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 600 400" width="600" height="400">
            <text id="t1" style="fill: white;" x="50%" y="50%" 
            text-anchor="middle">Test some long text here</text>
        </svg>
        <script>
function resize() {
    var width = 350,
      height = 80;
    var textNode = document.getElementById("t1");
    for (var k = 1; k < 60; k++) {
      textNode.setAttribute("font-size", k)
      var bb = textNode.getBBox()
      if (bb.width > width || bb.height > height)
        break;
    }
}

//window.onload = resize;
//waiting font loading
{
    var cnt = 0;
    function tryResize(){
        if(!ready() && cnt < 30){
            setTimeout(tryResize, 100);
            cnt++;
        }else{
            resize();
        }
    }
    //check the state of font loading
    var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    var c2 = c1.cloneNode(false);
    var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
    var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
    //set target font and fallback font 
    ctx1.font = "normal 30px 'Sonsie One', serif";
    ctx2.font = "normal 30px serif";
    var text = "this is test text.";  
    function ready(){
        //compare text length.
        //when the target font loading is complted, 
        //the legth of text will be changed
        return ctx1.measureText(text).width != ctx2.measureText(text).width;
    }
    //start waiting
    tryResize();
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

DEMO:http://jsdo.it/defghi1977/ueFO